# jQuery delay between two animations

Tags: jquery

Code:

```
   $("#telecomGrayscale", this).stop().animate({ top: '467px' }, 
    { duration: 400 }).delay(800).queue(function() {
                $("#boxcaptionTelecom", this).stop().animate({ top: '272px' }, { duration: 900 });
                });
```

The above code is not working as needed. The 2nd animation that is inside the queue () is not
working.

I just need to delay the second animation. Also tried setTimeout and setInterval could not get them to work.

Comment: Could you at least reveal how exactly it's not working as needed? Is it not doing the 2nd animation at all? Does it not delay the 2nd animation as expected?

Comment: The 2nd animation is not occurring at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second animation, the `this` is not what you think it is, so the selector with `this` as a context is most likely empty.

Try if this works:

```
var self = this;
$("#telecomGrayscale", self)
    .stop()
    .animate(
        { top: '467px' },
        { duration: 400 }
    )
    .delay(800)
    .queue(
        function() {
            $("#boxcaptionTelecom", self)
                .stop()
                .animate(
                    { top: '272px' },
                    { duration: 900 }
                );
            return $(this).dequeue();
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks!!.. had no idea about 'this'.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be in chain:

```
$("#telecomGrayscale", this).stop().animate({ top: '467px' }, 
{ duration: 400 }).delay(800).animate({ top: '272px' }, { duration: 900 });
```

edit:
Forgive my mistake. If you want to make it on two different elements, then you should make first parameter of queue() 'fx', and then, as second parameter your function. Look at function documentation at http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: It looks like he's trying to animate different elements, though.