# using requestAnimationFrame with wait time

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I've some basic script to scroll a text to the right and left which I tried to convert it from `timeout` to `requestAnimationFrame`, however, I can't make it work.

```
function slideHorizontal(e, amount, time) {

    var waitTime = 500;

    e.animate({
        marginRight: '-'+amount+'px'
    }, time, 'linear', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            e.animate({
                marginRight: 0
            }, time , 'linear', function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    slideHorizontal(e, amount, time);
                }, waitTime);
            });
        }, waitTime);
    });

}
```

any suggestion how I can apply the wait time with `requestFrameAnimation`? BTW, should I even use `jQuery.animate()` if I'm going to use the `requestFrameAnimation`?

Comment: Is this the code that used timeout? or have you modified this a bit?

Comment: @RandomUser This code uses `timeout` which can be found at the callback of the `animate` method. this is the current code I'm using

Answer (score 1):

No, `requestAnimationFrame()` does not make any sense when you use jQuery's `animate()`. jQuery may use `requestAnimationFrame()` internally though.

You can use `requestAnimationFrame()` to replace `setTimeout()` when you run the main animation loop with `setTimeout(f, x)`. Instead of having a animation frame every `x` ms, `requestAnimationFrame()` lets the browser control the frame rate. The actual rate will then be based on whatever the browser deems necessary for a smooth animation, depending on the hardware and other factors. The browser can also lower the refresh rate when the window/tab is not visible, to conserve CPU time and reduce power usage of animations that are not visible.

But that's not what you are using `setTimeout()` for. You use it to wait between two animations. There are [more elegant ways of doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863041/jquery-delay-between-two-animations), but `requestAnimationFrame()` isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

here's how you would use `requestAnimationFrame`:

```js
var i = 0;
var forward = true;
function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  if(i < 100 && forward){
    i+=2;
  }
  else if(i > 0){
    forward = false;
    i-=2;
  }
  else{i = 0; forward = true;}
  document.getElementById("div").style.left = i + "px";
}
draw();
```

```css
div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

The `setInterval` equivalent would be:

```js
var i = 0;
var forward = true;
function draw() {
  setInterval(function(){
  if(i < 100 && forward){
    i+=2;
  }
  else if(i > 0){
    forward = false;
    i-=2;
  }
  else{i = 0; forward = true;}
  document.getElementById("div").style.left = i + "px";},10);
}
draw();
```

```css
div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="div" onload="draw"></div>
```